# Would it be possible to get spoiler tags added to chat?

Tags: feature-request, chat, spoilers

It would make it a lot easier for people to do stuff like post a link to Puzzling, and then spoiler-tag some discussion about the answer in chat without ruining it for others who want to look.

Comment: I searched for this, and didn't find the dupe. Sorry.

Comment: No worry, not it will be easier to find.